# Error two or more assemblies Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.resources. C# Framework Reportviewer and ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, reportviewer

I am having an error to buy "PUBLISH" a program in the .NET Framework by using ClickONCE.

> Two or more assemblies have the same identity "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.resources, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=zh-CHS, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91, ProcessorArchitecture=msil".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. From the "Solution Explorer" pane, right click on the project (not solution) and choose "Properties"
2. Go to the "Publish" tab.
3. Click on the "Application Files..." button.
4. Find one of the two and set the "Publish Status" drop-down to "Exclude"